# Convert Mongo Db "No Field" to null values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have imported csv into Mongo DB Collections. CSV file contains some empty values, after loading when I check collection, empty  values are replaced by "No Field" . But I want to have them a "null" values. How Can I achieve this?

Thanks,

Jeggi

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
dbcollection.update_many(filter={'field_name': {'$exists': False}}, 
                         update={'$set': {'field_name': null}})
```